# SystemVerilog Coverage: Create a bin for each element of an enum

Tags: system-verilog

Say I have a enum which contains a list of valid commands or opcodes. 
Is there a way to create a bin for each element of the enum?

```
class command_coverage;
  enum {SEQ_WRITE_16_BIT = 32'hBEEFFOOD, SEQ_READ_16_BIT = 32'hFACEFACE, 
        ... } my_valid_commands

  covergroup cg();
    command_cp : coverpoint cmd {
                   bins valid_commands[] = each element of enum;
                 }
  endgroup

  ...

endclass
```

I tried something like:

```
bins valid_commands[] = my_valid_commands;
```

or

```
bins valid_commands[] = {[0:$] inside my_valid_commands};
```

But it didn't work as I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done:

```
command_cp : coverpoint my_valid_commands {
    bins valid_commands[] = {[my_valid_commands.first:my_valid_commands.last]};
```

`first` and `last` are *methods* of the enum, which return the first and last values respectively. These are then used as part of a range.

Here's the display from Mentor Questa (other simulators are available - I have Questa installed on my PC):

[image]

Here's an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5rUu

```
module enum_cg;

  enum {SEQ_WRITE_16_BIT, SEQ_READ_16_BIT} my_valid_commands;

  covergroup cg();
    command_cp : coverpoint my_valid_commands {
      bins valid_commands[] = {[my_valid_commands.first:my_valid_commands.last]};
                 }
  endgroup

  cg cg0 = new;

  initial begin
    my_valid_commands = SEQ_WRITE_16_BIT;
    cg0.sample;
  end    

endmodule
```

Comment: This is similar to what I was looking for, I am not sure if it's simulator dependent for how the bins are created (I use Synopsys VCS). VCS covers if each of the enum element been covered at least once but not how many iterations of each individual element of the enum using the code mentioned, using VCS. But still this is very useful especially when I start introducing more elements into the enum or when I start adding more enums in the future.

My workaround is to list each individual elements into the bin array:
`each_valid_command[] = {[SEQ_WRITE_16_BIT, SEQ_READ_16_BIT]}`